# Django/cx_Oracle with Oracle DRCP connection pooling

Tags: django, oracle, python-3.x, connection-pooling, cx-oracle

I need to use Oracle12 DRCP connection pooling with Django (1.8), cx_Oracle 5.2 and python33

Here is my configuration

**TNS name configuration**

```
TNS_NAME_DRCP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_host_name)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = MY_SID)
      (SERVER = POOLED)
    )
  )
```

**Django connection settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'TNS_NAME_DRCP',
        'USER': 'USERNAME',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 10000,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'purity': cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_SELF,
            'cclass': 'MY_CLASS_NAME',
            'threaded': True,
        },
    }
}
```

The connection and the application works fine.
But when I try to see if connection pooling is working by querying

```
SQL> select num_hits, num_misses,num_requests from v$cpool_cc_stats;
```

I get Zero Hits. (100% misses)
I checked following pages for additional information

[DATABASE RESIDENT CONNECTION POOLING (DRCP )](http://progeeking.com/2013/10/15/database-resident-connection-pooling-drcp/)
[DRCP with cx_Oracle doesn't appear to work as expected](http://www.wikiguga.com/topic/141755dc0abe85074f817d4509b1f8d9)

Any hints what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: Removing "'CONN_MAX_AGE': 10000," solved the problem

Comment: 'cclass': 'MY_CLASS_NAME', : What is MY_CLASS_NAME here ?

Comment: @fraggles - By chance, what did you set `CONN_MAX_AGE` to?